# Как реализовать в quiz приложении несколько разных тестов, не создавая дополнительных Activity для каждого

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как реализовать в quiz приложении несколько разных тестов, не создавая дополнительных Activity для каждого?

Comment: Используйте фрагменты.

Comment: В книгах П.Дейтел "Android для разработчиков" и Б.Филипс "Android.  Программирование для профессионалов" есть подробный разбор как создавать игру-викторину. В этих книгах вы найдете ответы на все возможные вопросы. А вообще вопрос не понятен, в чем именно проблема, почему нужно создавать дополнительные активити ..

Comment: Мне нужно создать несколько тестов с разным содержанием, и что бы не загрязнять приложение разными активити для каждого, нужно на макет отправить эти самые разные тексты

Comment: Ну, значит вам надо создать общую модель данных для разных тестов, передавать её в активити, а там в `switch` по типу данных отображать так или иначе. Но лучше, возможно, сделать отдельный фрагмент на каждый тест, если логика отображения сильно разная

Comment: спасибо, попробую сделать так